MS Vision Object Detection Evaluation Run Fails
I am using the "Recognise Products on Shelves" feature on the MS Vision Studio but am running into to trouble with the Evaluation Run.  For new models that I have trained the Evaluation set fails with the following error.

Batch did not complete successfully. OutputResultWriteFailed: An unexpected error was encountered.

Older models that I have trained the evaluation run had been successful but if I try a new evaluation run on the same model it now fails so trying to figure out what's changed.  Anyone experienced this error and if so how did you resolve it?
Thanks
